# Cannot extract attribute data

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I am trying to extract attribute. Attribute are custom attributes. [image]
But some how i am not able to use `object.id` thing.
For example my commented code `adpter.id` is not valid, even you see i have converted that object to its type.

Here is the code for the attribute:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
 public class Adapter : Attribute
 {
    // This class implements the Adapter Attribite
    readonly int id;
    readonly string Title;
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    private string[] Relation;

    public Adapter(int id, string Title,string []relations)
    {
       this.id = id;
       this.Title = Title;
       this.Relation = relations;
    }


}
```

Comment: In addition to answers below, you should use "-Attribute" suffix for your types, derived from System.Attribute. E.g. "AdapterAttribute".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default visibility for fields is private, try to make `id` and `Title` public.
You could also change the fields to properties with a private setter like this:

```
public Id { get; private set; }
public Title { get; private set; }
```

Or to readonly properties:

```
public Id { get { return id; }  }
public Title { get { return title; } }
```

As it is considered bad design to create public fields.

Comment: This is not readonly property. This is property with a private setter. There's difference between them.

Comment: That is correct, my bad. A readonly property doesn't have a setter. Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: `public readonly Id` makes the field readonly, it can only be set inline or in the constructor. `public Id` can be changed outside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to read id from another class? 
You are missing the public modifier.

```
public readonly int id;
```

Variables, properties and methods missing modifier will automatically become private.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I guess given a class's default behavior as private members, you can try to change it to `public`!